Why does Netlify does not serve the images and fonts from Express file?
I am new at coding and  for the first time I am deploying my app in Netlify and I am facing a problem. My Nodejs, Express file does not serve the images and the fonts. The HTML, CSS and JavaScript are working.
require('dotenv').config();
const express = require('express');
const serverless = require('serverless-http');
const path = require('path');
const app = express();

const router = express.Router();

const cors = require('cors');


app.use(cors());



app.use(express.json());


router.get('/products.json', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '/public/products.json'));
});

router.get('/products.json', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '/public/products.json'));
});

router.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../public/styles/fonts')));

 router.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../public/images')));

router.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../public'), {
    setHeaders: (res, filePath) => {
        const ext = path.extname(filePath);
        const mimeTypes = {
            '.html': 'text/html',
            '.js': 'application/javascript',
            '.css': 'text/css',
        };
        const contentType = mimeTypes[ext];
        if (contentType) {
            res.setHeader('Content-Type', contentType);
        }
    }
}));


router.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../public/styles/fonts'), {
    setHeaders: (res, filePath) => {
      const ext = path.extname(filePath);
      const mimeTypes = {
        '.ttf': 'application/font-ttf',
        '.otf': 'application/font-otf',
        '.eot': 'application/vnd.ms-fontobject',
        '.woff': 'application/font-woff',
        '.woff2': 'application/font-woff2',
        '.svg': 'image/svg+xml',
      };
      const contentType = mimeTypes[ext];
      if (contentType) {
        res.setHeader('Content-Type', contentType);
      }
    }
  }));


router.get("", (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../public/views', 'index.html'));
});



app.use('/', router);

module.exports.handler = serverless(app);

and this is my netlify.toml file
[build]
   functions="functions"

[[redirects]]
  to="/.netlify/functions/api/:splat"
  from="/*"
  status=200

There are the errors that are popping in the console when I deploy my page
Failed to decode downloaded font: 
http://localhost:8888/styles/fonts/Norms/NormsProMedium.ttf
localhost/:1 OTS parsing error: DSIG: misaligned table
localhost/:1 Failed to decode downloaded font: 

